# Check if regex pattern is correct

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-replace, preg-match

I just made a regex pattern for replace links to HTML anchor tags, this is it:

```
~((http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)([^ ]+)) ~
```

The reason why I ask this, is because I just finished this regex recently and made a few tests with some links, it works great but I want to be sure that there is no bugs with this pattern (I'm a regex newie) and maybe a regex expert could tell his opinion and / or suggestion.

By the way, if you're figuring out the space at the end, you may think it will not work if the string doesn't ends with a space, but my trick is to add that space to the string before the replacement and then remove it again once the stuff is done.

PD:

I don't take care of the link's validation itself, I just want to search for the strings that starts with http:// and ends with a space, nothing else, since link validation is a bit complicated.

EDIT:

Some of my code:

```
<?php

    $patron = "~(https?:\/\/[^\s]+) ~";
    //$patron = "~((http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)([^ ]+)) ~";
    $reemplazar = '<a href="$1">$1</a> ';
    $cadena = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7it5wioGixA ";

    echo preg_replace($patron, $reemplazar, $cadena);

?>
```

Comment: google search for 'regex tester'

Comment: @Donovan I did, and I used it, now I want to try 'StackOverflow experts tester' :-)

Comment: That's not really what this site is intended for, you don't actually have a question, you're looking for opinion.

Comment: Then, where should I ask this? and why it is not? still being a doubt, what if there is something wrong with it, and someone suggest to me to something better..?

Comment: Have a look at PHP's [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) function - especially the `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` option.

Comment: The site is intended to help users with programming problems when they are stuck, not discuss opinions on best practices.  You might try chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @BennyHill I want to use regex because I'm dealing with preg_replace

Comment: Would http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ be appropriate for discussing best practices/improvements?

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be greatly simplified:

```
~(https?://\S+) ~
```

Other than that: Looks okay to me.

Comment: No. I'm marking the "s" in "https" as optional via the question mark. `[^\s]` simply means "all characters except any form of whitespaces."

Comment: And `[^\s]+` can also be reduced to `\S+`

Answer (score 1):

With the same idea, your pattern can be shorten to :

```
~https?://[^\s"'>]+~    # don't forget to escape the quote you use.
```

To change URLs to links:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('~\b(?:(https?://)|www\.)[^]\s"\')<]++~',
    function ($m) {
        $pre = ($m[1]) ? $m[1] : 'http://'; 
        if (filter_var($pre . $m[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
            return '<a href="' . $m[0] . '">' . $m[0] . '</a>';
        else return $m[0];
    }, $html);
```

Old answer:

To change URLs inside links:

A better way to extract all href attributes from all "a" tags is to use the DOM.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($htmlString);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('href');
foreach($links as &$link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $link->setAttribute('href', 'what you want');
}
```

Comment: I don't want to extract the href of anchors, I want to convert links to anchors..

Comment: @Neo: In this case it will more complicated since URLs don't have always a protocol!

Comment: the main requirement for the link is that it contains the protocol at least, it's very simple..